# SwiftUI: Toolbar Button w/ .primaryAction is displayed offset on Apple Watch

Tags: button, swiftui, offset, watchos

I use a toolBarItem with the attribute .primaryAction in one view.
When I call the app on the Apple Watch, this button is displayed offset. I haven't found a way to change this yet. Is this a bug or am I making a mistake?

[The offset button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBo0.png)

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            sharedData.gameStatsView
                .environmentObject(sharedData) 
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .scrollIndicators(.never)
    
        }
        .toolbar { if sharedData.isGameEnd {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Button("\(Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down.fill")) Save & reset") {
                    saveGameFunc()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                .padding()
                .tint(.green).foregroundStyle(.white).font(.system(size: 14))    
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

I tried to fix it with .buttonStyle, but that didn't work.